# Apply returning DataFrame when it should return a Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Choose a random row from my pandas DataFrame
2. Subset the DataFrame to only include rows which match the randomly chosen row on 2 specific columns, 'Type' and 'LocationID'.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

train = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Type': ['Rad', 'Rad', 'Rad', 'Rad', 'Rad'], 
     'LocationID': ['6', '6', '6', '6', '6'], 
     'UserID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
u1 = train.sample(n=1)
group_feat = ['Type', 'LocationID']
for gf in group_feat:
    match = train[gf].apply(lambda x: x == u1[gf])
    train = train.loc[match]
```

My code is throwing an error on the last line from the .loc function:

> ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Further investigation revealed that the type of the variable `match` is not a Series, but a DataFrame with 1 column. I can't reckon why the apply function, in this instance, would not simply return a Series. How can I get around this? I can't use the usual `tolist()` since that method is not available for a DataFrame. Any insight into the general intuition of pandas that caused me to run into this error? I've successfully used `apply` many times before and in the past it returned the expected type.

**Edit:** `train.info()` (irrelevant columns removed for brevity/privacy):

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 92529 entries, 0 to 92528
Data columns (total 93 columns):
Type                                              92529 non-null object
LocationID                                        92529 non-null object
 UserID                                            92529 non-null int64
 dtypes: float64(6), int64(55), object(32)
 memory usage: 66.4+ MB
 None
```

Comment: Please post `train.head().todict('list')` and `train.info()` so we can (hopefully) reproduce the problem.

Comment: @unutbu The former caused an`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'todict'` but I edited the question to include the latter. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry -- that should have read `train.head().to_dict('list')` (with an underscore).

Comment: Whoops! added @unutbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.Series.apply(func)` will return a `Series` if `func` returns a scalar, or [will return a `DataFrame` if `func` returns a `Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas-series-apply).

`u1[gf]` is a Series so `lambda x: x == u1[gf]` returns a boolean Series, and so `match` ends up being a DataFrame.

When using `df.loc[key]`, `key` can be a slice, a boolean sequence, or a list-like indexer, but it can not be a DataFrame. When `key` is a DataFrame, a `ValueError('Cannot index with multidimensional key')` is raised.

---

To fix the problem, you could use

```
match = train[gf].apply(lambda x: x == u1[gf].item())
```

Since [`u1[gf].item()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) is a scalar and so `lambda x: x == u1[gf].item()` returns a boolean scalar (and so `match` ends up being a Series.)

Or, for better performance, a better way to write this would be

```
for gf in group_feat:
    train = train.loc[train[gf] == u1[gf].item()]
```

avoiding the use of `apply` with a lambda function altogether.

And to save memory (and improve performance), avoid forming the intermediate DataFrame(s) by replacing

```
group_feat = ['Type', 'LocationID']
for gf in group_feat:
    match = train[gf].apply(lambda x: x == u1[gf])
    train = train.loc[match]
```

with

```
mask = (train['Type'] = u1['Type'].item()) 
        and (train['LocationID'] = u1['LocationID'].item())
train = train.loc[mask]
```

or more generally,

```
group_feat = ['Type', 'LocationID']
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([train[col] == u1[col].item() for col in group_feat])
train = train.loc[mask]
```

The latter is especially useful when `group_feat` is long.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Type': ['Rad', 'Rad', 'Rad', 'Rad', 'Rad'], 
     'LocationID': ['6', '6', '6', '6', '6'], 
     'UserID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
u1 = train.sample(n=1)
group_feat = ['Type', 'LocationID']
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([train[col] == u1[col].item() for col in group_feat])
train = train.loc[mask]
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the `item()` function is the thing I was looking for but didn't know how to look for. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: sorry I took so long to reply but this work perfectly for me thanks again!